# How can I configure doxygen to generate html with plain list of files?

Tags: c#, doxygen, xml-comments, doxygen-wizard

I have a project with tree like structure written in C#. I need to list all *.cs files in plain list with comments.
For example:
MyProject

> Models
>
> > - Model1.cs
> > - Model2.cs
>
> Controllers
>
> > - Controller1.cs
> > - Controller2.cs
>
> Views
>
> > - View1.cshtml
> > - View2.cshtml

etc.

Each file has section of xml comments, for instance:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;

namespace MyProject.DefaultNamespace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Some important comment
    /// </summary>
    public class Model1
    {
    }
}
```

I want to generate rtf file with such structure or table:
Model1.cs       | Some important comment
Model2.cs       | Some important comment1
Controller1.cs       | Some important comment2
Controller2.cs       | Some important comment3
View1.cshtml       | Some important comment4
View2.cshtml       | Some important comment5

In other words, I want to generate not documentation, but description of each file by its summary xml comment in list structure.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? In the title of your question you speak of HTML and in the question itself about RTF, are you interested in HTML or RTF? You could try to generated the XML documentation (`GENERATE_XML=YES`) and posprocess the information from the resulting files.

Comment: Note: the mentioned summary information in the example is for the class, not for the file. What kind of information do you want?

Comment: In fact, it doesn't matter in what format to get this description: HTML or RTF. It is determined by checkbox at settings. Each file contains one class, so presence of summary comment will be enough for file description. I'm using  doxygen GUI of 1.8.18 version.

Comment: I don't think you can accomplish this directly in doxygen without pre or post processing.